# Are the following patents European only? EP 1849393 B1 and WO2005108015 (A1)

Tags: international, jurisdiction

These are patents by a cleaning company in Denmark named Vikan. I would like to understand if these are patents that are European only or also US patents. Also, when I look on the European patent website, Espacenet, on INPADOC legas Status for WO2005108015, it shows PRS Code WWW as one of the last PRS dates and says, WIPO INFORMATION: WITHDRAWN IN NATIONAL OFFICE". Does that mean that they withdrew their patent application for this item?

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer you with.

1) If a patent is of series EPXXX..XX, it is filed only in EP. It doesn't get patent rights in US. 
2) WO2005108015 is a WIPO application. It gives an inventor liberty/time to file patents in other countries taking priority from WIPO application.
3) So, after filing WIPO application, the inventor can file another patent in US and other countries.
4) Basically, same invention is filed in different countries.
5) And, these are clubbed under one as a 'family members'.

Specifically, in your case, WO2005108015, has only two members. DK200400741 and WO2005108015. So, as it doesn't have any US patents in family.

Comment: Not quite. The WO is only an application. The record for the DK shows as legal status 2008/01/21 APPLICATION SHELVED FOR OTHER REASONS THAN NON-PAYMENT and so has no validity. However, the header mentions an EP. These are also to Vikan and the inventor is Anders Florvik. The family consists of DK176309, EP1849393 and NO20072182. The DK and NO statuses are not available on Espacenet but the EP appears to have been maintained (fees paid) in DE, GB, SE and FR at least. You are right, of course, that there is no US validity.